# Botocore Exceptions : No Credentials Error: Unable to locate credentials in virtual environment using Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, heroku, boto3, credentials

I am using the Heroku for deploying the Python API. I am using the python to implement Amazon comprehend. For doing this, I am able to configure the ACCESS keys and secret access keys in .aws folder by aws configure command in my local system. It is running fine. But when I deployed into the Heroku, it is facing the exception indicating couldn't locate the credentials.

Runs in the local system but Exception during Heroku deployment process.

The difference in the local system and Heroku is: I have created the virtual environment and then deployed my app using Heroku into it during deployment.

Some logs that I can shared is:

```
2019-04-16 21:10:06,944 botocore.endpoint [DEBUG] Making request for OperationModel(name=DetectKeyPhrases) with params: {'url_path': '/', 'query_string': '', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'X-Amz-Target': 'Comprehend_20171127.DetectKeyPhrases', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'User-Agent': 'Boto3/1.9.130 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.4.0-1038-aws Botocore/1.12.130'}, 'body': b'{"Text": "\\"Iam a good graduate\\"", "LanguageCode": "en"}', 'url': 'https://comprehend.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/', 'context': {'client_region': 'us-east-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7f37df8a9be0>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}
2019-04-16T21:10:06.945741+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-04-16 21:10:06,945 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event request-created.comprehend.DetectKeyPhrases: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f37df8a9ba8>>
2019-04-16T21:10:06.946459+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-04-16 21:10:06,946 botocore.hooks [DEBUG] Event choose-signer.comprehend.DetectKeyPhrases: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7f37dfcc32f0>
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948550+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-04-16 21:10:06,947] ERROR in app: Exception on /testAlgorithm [GET]
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948554+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948556+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948557+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948559+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948561+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948562+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948564+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948565+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948567+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948569+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948570+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948572+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948574+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948575+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 43, in test
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948577+00:00 app[web.1]: return json.dumps(algo.Algorithms().process_algorithm(query_str, data_id, crawledId, 0))
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948579+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/algorithms.py", line 33, in process_algorithm
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948580+00:00 app[web.1]: data.extend(self.comprehend_algo(text, id, uniqueId, flag))
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/algorithms.py", line 39, in comprehend_algo
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948584+00:00 app[web.1]: index_keyword = dict(comprehend.detect_key_phrases(Text=text, LanguageCode='en'))
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948586+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948587+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948589+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948590+00:00 app[web.1]: operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948592+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948594+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948596+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948598+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948599+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 132, in _send_request
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948601+00:00 app[web.1]: request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948603+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 116, in create_request
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948604+00:00 app[web.1]: operation_name=operation_model.name)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948606+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948608+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948609+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948611+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948613+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948614+00:00 app[web.1]: response = handler(**kwargs)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948616+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948618+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.sign(operation_name, request)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 157, in sign
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948622+00:00 app[web.1]: auth.add_auth(request)
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948624+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948625+00:00 app[web.1]: raise NoCredentialsError
2019-04-16T21:10:06.948715+00:00 app[web.1]: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Comment: Please share your code snippet where you are getting this exception.

Comment: @ninad. I believe code doesnt have the issue. The problem is during deployment in production, it is not able to grab the credentials using shared credentials.

Comment: Try to set the environment variable `$HOME` to point to the home directory of the user who is running the code or set `$AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` to point to the user's credential file, usually in `$HOME/.aws/`